# Creating an hourglass using asterisks

Tags: java

I would like to create an hourglass using the "*" character. For example if the user input was 5 then it would look like this:

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

and 3 would look like this:

```
 ***
  *
 ***
```

So far I have:

```java
public static void draw(int W){
    stars(W);
    if (W > 1) {
        draw(W-1);
        stars(W);
    }
}
public static void stars(int n){
    System.out.print("*");
    if(n>1) stars(n-1);
    else System.out.println();
}
```

and it creates

```
 *****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *
 **
 ***
 ****
```

---

Comment: looks a lot with those tests that ask you to print a pyramid or an inverted pyramid. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069304/make-a-upside-down-triangle-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356537/how-to-draw-a-pyramid

Comment: The draw() should be called with an odd number and use -2 instead of -1, otherwise you won't be able to center anything.

Comment: Short answer: print a number of spaces (hint: 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 when n = 5) and go down, then up in stars in twos (5,3,1,3,5). Take it from there.

Comment: I don't know java much, but in PHP i would do it with a simple for loop with `str_pad` and `str_repeate` The Code i PHP: `$W = 5;for ($i=$W; $i >= -($W) ; $i-=2) {if ($i<>1) echo str_pad(str_repeat("*", abs($i)), abs($W),' ',2), "\n";}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete solution in Java

```
public static void draw(int w){
    draw(w, 0);
}

public static void draw(int W, int s){
    stars(W, s);
    if (W > 2) {
        draw(W-2, s+1);
        stars(W, s);
    }
}
public static void stars(int n, int s){
    if(s > 0){
        System.out.print(" ");
        stars(n, s-1);
    } else  if (n > 0){
        System.out.print("*");
        stars(n-1, s);
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the parameter s was introduced to keep track of the number of spaces needed to center the asterisks
Another way to do this would be have some global parameter to keep track of the total width and do subtraction but you seem to really like recursion.

This code

```
for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
    System.out.println("An hourglass of width " + i);
    draw(i);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Will now output this

```
An hourglass of width 1
*

An hourglass of width 2
**

An hourglass of width 3
***
 *
***

An hourglass of width 4
****
 **
****

An hourglass of width 5
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****

An hourglass of width 6
******
 ****
  **
 ****
******
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
function stars(n):
  c1 = 0
  c2 = n
  for i = 1 to n
    print ' ' * c1
    print '*' * c2
    if (i < (n+1) / 2):
      c1 ++;
      c2 -=2;
    else:
      c1--
      c2 +=2
    print newline
```

This should get you close to your answer... now translate into java

** note - this works for odd number. You may need to tweak for even n **