# how to draw an hourglass in java

Tags: java

I just need some pointers. I am new to java and busy with a task that prints am hourglass. what i am trying to do is write the program so that it will accepts a char from a user and then output an hourglass in the console. this is the instructions.

In this question, you are tasked to complete the implementation of the printHourglass(int, char) method for printing out an hourglass of a specific size and symbol.

Instructions

Given the parameters size = n and the character symbol.

You can assume that n is a positive odd number.

The hourglass consists of n lines.

The character symbol will appear a number of times in each line. The symbol will appear n times in the first line. The number of times the symbol printed will be decreased by 2 in each subsequent line until it reaches 1. After that, the number of times the symbol printed will be increased by 2 in each subsequent line until it reaches n again.
Spaces are added to the start and end of each line so that the total width of each line is n and the symbols in each line are aligned at the center of each line.

For outputting, you can use either System.out.print()/println() or IO.output()/outputln().

i have seen quite a few posts online but none of then take input or asks for user input or how big the hourglass should be. One that i found that works is this method to output the hourglass

```
public static void stars(int n, int s){
    if(s > 0){
        System.out.print(" ");
 stars(n, s-1);
} else  if (n > 0){
    System.out.print("*");
    stars(n-1, s);
} else {
    System.out.println();
}
```

but this will only print the it with an asterix. i was thinking of starting my method like this

public static void printHourglass( int size, char symbol)

i obviously dont want to copy other peoples code so please give me some pointers as to how i can get his method to work.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Recursion.

To print a line, you need the following

- The character to draw the hourglass (`char character`)
- The odd number you read from the user ( `int oddNumber`)
- The index of the current line being drawn (`int currentLine`)

For any odd number, say n, *hourglass has n lines*.

### Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int oddNumber = 5;
    char character = '#';
    hourglass(oddNumber, character, 0);

} 

public static void hourglass(int oddNumber, char character, int currentLine) {
    if (currentLine == oddNumber) {
        return;
    }

    int patternLength = 0;
    
    int mid = (oddNumber + 1) / 2;
    
    if (currentLine < mid) {
        patternLength = oddNumber - (currentLine * 2);
    } else {
        patternLength = 2 * (currentLine - mid + 1) + 1;
    }
    
    char[] whitespace = new char[(oddNumber - patternLength)/2];
    Arrays.fill(whitespace, ' ');

    char[] pattern = new char[patternLength];
    Arrays.fill(pattern, character);
    System.out.println(new String(whitespace) + new String(pattern));

    hourglass(oddNumber, character, currentLine + 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry im am trying to test the code but there is an error by line25 with the Array.fill

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;` add it at the top with other import statements @RyanD1987

Comment: ok cool i was able to run your code and it ran perfectly but i dont want to copy your whole code so im trying to put it in my own format and this is what i currently done havent changed it a lot yet but its not working.

Comment: here is what i done public static void hourglass(int size, char symbol) {int currentLine; if (currentLine == size) {return;}
    int patternLength = 0;
    int mid = (size + 1) / 2;
    if (currentLine < mid) {
        patternLength = size - (currentLine * 2);} else {patternLength = 2 * (currentLine - mid + 1) + 1;}
char[] whitespace = new char[(size - patternLength)/2];
Arrays.fill(whitespace, ' ');
char[] pattern = new char[patternLength];
    Arrays.fill(pattern, symbol);
    System.out.println(new String(whitespace) + new String(pattern));

    hourglass(size, symbol, currentLine + 1);
}

Answer (score 0):

I get the code from the [Creating an hourglass using asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031016/creating-an-hourglass-using-asterisks) And changed it little bit so you can give character. You can change the name of `draw(int w , char c)` method to the method name that is given to you like `printHourglass(int w, char c)`

```
public static void draw(int w , char c) {
    draw(w, 0, c);
}

public static void draw(int W, int s, char c) {
    stars(W, s,c);
    if (W > 2) {
       draw(W - 2, s + 1, c);
       stars(W, s,c);
    }
}

public static void stars(int n, int s, char c) {
    if (s > 0) {
       System.out.print(" ");
       stars(n, s - 1, c);
    } else if (n > 0) {
       System.out.print(c);
       stars(n - 1, s, c);
    } else {
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```