# Problems with nested for loop hourglass

Tags: java, nested-loops

I really need help with nested for loops. I am trying to make a program that makes an hourglass but I can't figure out how to do it using nested loops. So far I have this:

```
/** program design pseudocode

 * Part A: Draw the bars and quotations (top bar)

 * Part B: Spacing, forward slash, colons, and backslash

 *      Part E, Part D

 * Part C: Proper spacing and then print two bars

 * Part B Reversed: Spacing, forward slash, colons, backslash

 *      Part E reversed, Part D reversed

 * Part A  

 */

package inceptloops;

/**

 * @author bryan_000

 *

 */

public class Hourglass {

//Part A
public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawPartA();
    drawPartB();
    drawPartC();
    drawPartBReversed();
    drawPartA();

}

// Produces Part A
public static void drawPartA() {
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("\"");
    }
    System.out.print("|");
}

// This produces the top part of the hourglass, part b.
public static void drawPartB() {
    for(int b = 1; b <= 1; b++) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" \\::::::::/");
        System.out.println("  \\::::::/");
        System.out.println("   \\::::/");
        System.out.println("    \\::/");
```

My problem is that I created the second part of the hourglass but it's not a nested for loop like it should be. I have no clue how to figure this out so any help is appreciated.

This is how it is supposed to look:

```
        |""""""""""|
         \::::::::/
          \::::::/
           \::::/
            \::/
             ||
            /::\
           /::::\
          /::::::\
         /::::::::\
        |""""""""""|
```

Comment: What does any of this have to do with nested `for` loops?  Also, where's the rest of your code?  It just ends part-way through a method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an hourglass using asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031016/creating-an-hourglass-using-asterisks)

Answer (score 0):

Try to visit this post, i dont quite understand your question, but this may help you. [Creating an hourglass using asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031016/creating-an-hourglass-using-asterisks)